# MySQL Array SELECT & UPDATE Statements Based on Index Position

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

Please consider the image of my table below, my questions concern performing an `UPDATE` and `SELECT` on the `sensor_values` column.

[image]

`sensor_values` column is an array of length 86,400 corresponding to the value of the sensor at each second of the day. I set it up as `JSON` data type for now.

**My Questions**

How do I perform an `UPDATE` on a specific index?

- *i.e.* Change the 5th second of the day, or index `[4]` to the value `300.25`

How do I `SELECT` the first 300 seconds of the day? *pseudocode below*

```sql
SELECT sensor_values[0:299] FROM facts WHERE d_date = '2020-03-10' AND dim_tag = 'Water_Temp'
```

Here is a link to a DBFiddle for PostGresql doing something very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish in MariaDB.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6999d2607c48a809ff995c8844c7f7bb

**EDIT: A high-level overview of my system below**

I have a Python data pipeline that reads the values of thousands of sensors and performs calculations. It is responsible for all data summation which is stored in other tables.

I need the data at the second level to be easily accessible for analysis, which I'm trying to do in the way spoken about in this problem. My thought is to get the second of the current day in Python, and use that as the array index to update, similar to below:

```py
now = datetime.datetime.now()
midnight = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
secondsSinceMidnight = (now - midnight).seconds

sensorValue =  300.25
sensorTag = "Water_Temp"

sqlQuery = 
"""
UPDATE facts
SET sensor_values[%s] = %s
WHERE d_date = %s AND dim_tag = %s
"""
sqlValues = secondsSinceMidnight, sensorValue, datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), sensorTag

dbOps.update(sqlQuery, sqlValues)
```

I don't want to track the values in Python throughout the entire day and then perform an `INSERT`, because if the program crashes I would lose all of the data, and using a *pre-formed array* lets me quickly programatically determine where data is missing in other areas of my program (i.e. `sensor_value` is a `0` for a set of seconds in the day).

I use the term *pre-formed array* because I plan to have my program periodically check to ensure there is always a row available for each sensor for the current & next day, ensuring seamless transitions at midnight since the grain is very small.

As suggested in Bill Karwin's answer, this was my first approach- however there are thousands of sensors, and each one will post every second. The database would grow exponentially: `1000 * 86400 = 86.4M` rows entered per day.

So, it doesn't have to be `JSON`, just an array modifiable in this format. I thought this was the correct approach with `MySQL`. Updated title of the post to better reflect the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use SQL to work with individual elements of your set of sensor values, then don't store it in JSON. Store it as rows in a normal table.

```
CREATE TABLE facts (
 d_date DATE NOT NULL,
 second INT NOT NULL,
 dim_tag VARCHAR(...) NOT NULL,
 sensor_value NUMERIC(5,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (d_date, second)
);
```

Then the queries you want are more straightforward to do in SQL:

```
UPDATE facts SET sensor_value = 300.25 WHERE d_date = '2020-03-10' AND second = 4;

SELECT sensor_value FROM facts WHERE d_date = '2020-03-10' AND second < 300;
```

If you insist on storing the sensor values as an array of JSON, there's no simple way of manipulating individual elements using SQL. You should just fetch the whole array into your application, and then unpack the JSON into an array you can read or change using code.

This is the weakness of using JSON: It's easy to insert a collection of values into a single column, and it's easy to fetch the whole collection as one unit. But it's quite awkward if you want to use SQL logic to work with individual elements of that collection.

Could someone post an answer that would give you the results you ask for in your question above? Probably, but it would take too long to develop, and the next time you want to do any other kind of task with this data, you'd have to ask for help again.

Using JSON when you really want discrete data elements is not a sustainable design, because it causes the software development costs to increase too high.

---

Re your additional information:

MySQL does not support an array data type or any syntax using array subscripts like you suppose.

I agree that 86.4 million rows per day is a rapid growth rate. You would reach over 1 billion rows in less than two weeks.

It could be that you need a time-series database instead of a relational database. Time-series databases optimize for long streams of similar data, and running aggregation queries over columns. They accept fast ingestion of these data streams, also store the data more compactly than a database engine like InnoDB.

You should take a look at one of these:

- https://www.influxdata.com
- http://opentsdb.net
- https://aws.amazon.com/timestream/ (still in preview as of March 2020)
- https://www.timescale.com

Comment: Bill, thank you very much for your insight. I've edited the question to include some more information about my system- I wanted to keep it general to make this more applicable for someone who lands here in the future, but I'm hopeful the additional information will help identify a solution to my issue.

Comment: Bill, thanks for the info. this was the push in the right direction I needed. I'm using TimeScaleDB (PostGres based) since it's close to the SQL syntax I'm familiar with and was able to accomplish my project with it.

Comment: Cool, I will add the link to TimeScaleDB to my answer above. I'm glad you found a good solution!